# What's the best way to change an image multiple times in many labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need some advice about how to approach this project. I have some programming experience, many years ago, but only started getting into Python in the past few weeks.

This Python 3 program has a tkinter screen with 150 icons on it. The icons are label widgets which display one of three 20x20 png graphics depending on states of a device which are read into the program from text files. Each icon needs to change several times a day.

Any advice on which method would work, to display these icons, in this situation would be appreciated.

I've had a few attempts. Ideally, a StringVar()/textvariable type approach would be good (which works great for changing text in a label) but I can't find a similar approach for images. Simply pushing the same label to the screen over and over doesn't work as the program eventually crashes 'out of memory'.

Edit:
I have approached this problem using key/value pairs so each loop doesn't create a new label. The method works on a single instance, but once I put it into this looping structure it crashes with "*TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment*". I've created this simple routine which mirrors the issue I am having with the larger project. How can I get this to work?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("PiStatus")
window.geometry("500x500+0+0")

ct = 0
# You can use any small images for this, mine are 20x20 pixels.
pc_on_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")
pc_active_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file="2.png")
pc_off_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file="0.png")

# This loop creates the base 15x10 grid of labels, each with a unique name.
for ypos in range(10):
    for xpos in range(15):
        label_name = "icon" + str(xpos) + "-" + str(ypos)
        label_name = tk.Label(window, image=pc_on_icon)
        label_name.grid(row=ypos, column=xpos)

while True:

# These statements cycle through the 3 images
    if ct == 0:
        turn = pc_off_icon
    elif ct == 1:
        turn = pc_on_icon
    else:
        turn = pc_active_icon

# This loop references each label giving it a different image each time around.
    for ypos in range(10):
        for xpos in range(15):
            label_name = "icon" + str(xpos) + "-" + str(ypos)
            label_name['image'] = turn  # This is where the error occurs.

    ct += 1

    if ct == 3:
        ct = 0

    window.update()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I would recommend for you to provide the code sample you are working on , even if you are asking for suggestions, it might help understand the context better.

Comment: Create labels for all the states, and only make those that correspond to the current device states visible.

Comment: Thank you so much Dan. Custom widgets are not something I had come across yet. This approach looks very interesting, it will take me some time to digest and work this method into my code. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: No problem. You don't really need to have a `Frame` derived class, you could just shove all the 450 labels into a single list and do basic maths to calculate the correct indices... it just seems like a nicer way to structure the code.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like this will work Dan. Examining the code it looks like each loop is still creating a new label instance. I ran it for an hour and it has eaten 14M of available memory while running. I am running it on a raspberry pi so memory isn't that big to begin with. Full disclosure, I don't have the pil module loaded, and it isn't required to show png files so I removed it from your code. But I don't think that would affect these results. I would like this to run without having to reboot every day to free up memory.

Comment: This has been solved. It's been a learning experience getting my head around how labels work, that if you set Label_1=...... you can't push an element into Label_1, it is not a variable. You have to create a reference to what comes after Label_1 and keep it in memory. What I did was create a list that contains an ID based on the x/y co-ords of the label position, then the label. Appending these two items to the list for each label. Then later in the program I can reference the ID and the label is the next element.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a custom widget to encapsulate the functionality of showing multiple state icons for one particular device. Let's call it `MultiStateIcon` and derive it from `tk.Frame`.

This widget will hold a collection of child `tk.Label` widgets, one per possible state/image. All the labels will fill overlap, however only one (that corresponding to the current state) will be visible (the others can be hidden using `pack_forget()`).

Then you just need to create a grid of `MultiStateIcon`s (or whatever layout you desire) and just change their state as the text file indicates.

---

For demonstration, I've made the application periodically (every 10ms) set the state of one randomly selected device to a randomly selected state.

Sample script:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
from random import randrange


class MultiStateIcon(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, images, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.images = images
        self.labels = []
        
        for image in images:
            l = tk.Label(self, image = image)
            l.pack()
            self.labels.append(l)
            
        self.set_state(0)
        
    def set_state(self, n):
        for i in range(len(self.labels)):
            if i == n:
                self.labels[i].pack()
            else:
                self.labels[i].pack_forget()
        
class TestApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, image_paths, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       
        self.title("Test")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        
        self.images = []
        for image_path in image_paths:
            img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(image_path))
            self.images.append(img)
        
        self.icons = []
        for r in range(10):
            for c in range(15):
                icon_lbl = MultiStateIcon(self.frame, self.images)
                icon_lbl.grid(row=r, column=c)
                self.icons.append(icon_lbl)
                
        self.after(1000, self.change_random_icon)
    
    def change_random_icon(self):
        n = randrange(0, len(self.icons))
        state = randrange(0, len(self.images))
        self.icons[n].set_state(state)
        self.after(10, self.change_random_icon)

def run():
    app = TestApp(["multiicon_0.png", "multiicon_1.png", "multiicon_2.png"])    
    app.mainloop()
    
run()
```

Images I used:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Screenshots of the app (one at the beginning, other after a little while -- memory usage seems to be stable):

[image]

[image]